# How to programatically change font size of android device?

Tags: android

I am making an app that has three buttons. Small, Medium and Large.I want my app to change the font size setting of the device according to the button clicked.Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: You can't change device properties until your device is not rooted and your app has root permission

Answer (score 0):

add setOnClickListener() to each button and do textview.setTextSize() for which you want to change. The number you set is in unit SP

Comment: I want to do something similar to the "Big Font" app on Play Store.It works for devices that are not rooted as well.

Comment: I want to change the font size of the entire phone, just like you change it from settings->Display->Font Size.The only change being i want some buttons in my app to represent each size.